# How to access itertools object in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have defined a get_queryset() method where i want to return two queryset objects like:

```
get_queryset(self):
    r1 = Books.objects.filter(auther_id=1);
    r2 = Books.objects.filter(~Q(auther_id=1));
    return r1,r2
```

The call to this method comes from a javascript file with an ajax call.
Now i want to access r1 and r2 individually in the js file.
I tried doing

```
r=chain(r1,r2) // in views.py

r.r1.fieldName  and r.r2.fieldName  // in js file.
```

I am unsure how could i unchain the itertools object. If it is not possible can anyone tell me about some other approach for this.

I also see method like ifilter() and etc to access the object but i want to access it in js.

EDIT: I have edited the code . CAN i club both query like

```
Books.objects.all()
```

and in the js do something to get two lists one having books by auther_id 1 and second list having other auther ids.

Comment: It doesnt make any sense to downvote. Since DOWNVOTE can be done by people having x reputation on SO i think instead of downvoting they should comment what could be done to increase the quality of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense at all. You can't 'unchain' something; the whole point of `chain` is that it makes the individual elements into one single undifferentiated item, there is no way of telling where one of the originals ended and the next started.

If you want to access two querysets individually in the template, then pass two individual querysets.

Comment: get_queryset method doesnt allow to pass multiple queryset object. Can you please suggest any other method for this

Comment: Override the `get_context_data` method and pass what you need from there.

Comment: thanx.  What i tried is i did query like Books.objects.all() and in the js i am now trying to differentiate the records based on the auther id. Is it fine ?